# Horizontal expand animation starting from the center of another View to it left bound

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to a make a horizontal fill animation from the center to the edges of a other view.
First i have centralized the view that will do the expand animation on the center of the main view and then animate with a `ScaleXTo` to the main view width:

XAML code:

```
    <StackLayout Padding="16" Spacing="10">
    
        <Grid
            Margin="0,0,0,16">
            <BoxView
                x:Name="firstView"
                BackgroundColor="Blue"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                HeightRequest="30"
                WidthRequest="180" />
    
            <BoxView
                x:Name="secondView"
                BackgroundColor="Black"
                HeightRequest="10"
                Scale="1"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="1" />
        </Grid>
    
        <Button
            Clicked="Button_OnClicked"
            Text="Animate!" />
    </StackLayout>
```

The code behind:

```
    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        secondView.TranslationX = firstView.Bounds.Center.X;
        secondView.ScaleXTo(firstView.Width);
    }
```

When executed, the animated view becomes larger than the main view, as can be seen on the print below

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo41z.png)

Comment: You want the nimation to expand the width only, to be the same as the first view? I don't understand why the translation or you want to scale and position at the same time ?

Comment: Hi, i forgot to add on the question about the origin of the animation! I'm trying to make the expand animation starts on the center of the firstView, so that when the second view is animated its expands to the firstView edges. So, the TranslationX centralize the second view to start expand.

Comment: So you want it to expand in both directions starting from the center?

Comment: Yep! I may be forgeting some value for the calculation when setting the scaleX.
I'm new on xamarin forms, but as far that i know the scaleX property acts like a muliplier to the X width, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Since you explained in the comment that you want animation to start from the centre, I am updating the answer.
Looks like there is a bug in Xamarin with scaling, since for some values of the WidthRequest and ScaleX it works as expected. For example, this implementation can do the trick for you:

```
    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double scale = 6;
        double startWidth = firstView.Width / scale;
        secondView.TranslationX = firstView.Bounds.Center.X - startWidth / 2;
        secondView.WidthRequest = startWidth;
        secondView.ScaleXTo(scale, 1000);
    }
```

but it will not work for bigger values of `scale`, ie. it will go outside of the `firstView`.
So, it is better to go with something like [@Cfun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5228202/cfun) proposed. The only problem with his solution is that it will expand `secondView` to the entire `firstView`. Also, I'm using `Task`, since yours `Button_OnClicked` is not `async` method:

```
        private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var rectangle = new Rectangle(secondView.X, secondView.Y, firstView.Width, secondView.Height);
            secondView.TranslationX = firstView.Bounds.Center.X;
            Task translate = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => secondView.TranslateTo(rectangle.Left, 0, 500));
            Task layout = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => secondView.LayoutTo(rectangle, 500));
            Task.WaitAll(new[] { translate, layout });
        }
```

**Old answer**:
If just horizontal filling is what you are trying to achieve, there is no need for translation and then scaling. You can just implement `Button_OnClicked` like this:

```
    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondView.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(secondView.X, secondView.Y, firstView.Width, secondView.Height));
    }
```

Comment: That works! But i forgot to mention on the question description that what i am trying to archive is that the animation starts at the center of the firstView and expand to his edges, with LayoutTo it aways starts from the left to the right :)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the proposal on how you can get the animation to start from the centre.

Comment: Thanks! The second solution with the tasks did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with two animations running concurrently in order to have a smooth visual, translation and resizing (`LayoutTo`)

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secondView.TranslationX = firstView.Bounds.Center.X;
    secondView.TranslateTo(firstView.Bounds.Left, 0, 500);
    await secondView.LayoutTo(firstView.Bounds, 500);
}
```

Comment: That works, but will fill the entire firstView and i just want to fill it up to its left and right sides from the center. @adamm 's second solution did the trick for me, thanks for the help!

Comment: My bad didn't understand the question well, you're welcome thanks for the feedback, you may want to update the title to be more detailed/specific so future readers will instantly understand it "BoxView horizontally expand animation starting from the center of another BoxView to it left bound" ?